# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop has no compress/extract in menu

Tags: 20.04

If I right-click a folder from the desktop I do not see "Compress" nor do I see "Extract" or "Extract to" when right-clicking a zip on the desktop.

However if I view those folders/files in then file manager then right-clicking shows the usual compress/extract options in the menu.